# Category and subcategory API node design

Tags: node.js, api, express

I am creating an ecommerce project, so there will be like a category ('men'), and subcategory of it "men's shoes", and an admin user can use addcategory in the mongodb, I found some code snippet from youtube, but the logic is so confusing, and I have no idea. can anyone kindly explain the step to step how to create this type of API?

in my category model file, I have this:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const categorySchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: { type: String, required: true, unique: true, trim: true },
    slug: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    parentID: {
      type: String,
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("Category", categorySchema);
```

in the category controller file:

```
const Category = require("../models/category");
const slugify = require("slugify");

function createCategories(categories, parentId = null) {
  const categoryList = [];
  let category;
  if (parentId == null) {
    categories.filter((cat) => cat.parentId == undefined);
  } else {
    category = categories.filter((cat) => cat.parentId === parentId);
  }

  for (let cate of category) {
    categoryList.push({
      _id: cate._id,
      name: cate._name,
      slug: cate.slug,
      children: createCategories(categories.cate._id),
    });
  }
  return categoryList;
}

exports.addCategory = (req, res) => {
  const categoryObj = {
    name: req.body.name,
    slug: slugify(req.body.name),
  };

  if (req.body.parentId) {
    categoryObj.parentId = req.body.parentId;
  }

  const cat = new Category(categoryObj);
  cat.save((error, category) => {
    if (error) return res.status(400).json({ error });
    if (category) {
      return res.status(201).json({ category });
    }
  });
};

exports.getCategories = (req, res) => {
  Category.find({}).exec((error, categories) => {
    if (error) console.log(error);

    if (categories) {
      const categoryList = createCategories(categories);

      res.status(200).json({ categoryList });
    }

    if (categories) {
      res.status(200).json({ categories });
    }
  });
};
```